# Why does creating a new fold sometimes cause the entire file to be folded?

Tags: vim, vim-folding

Sometimes when I create a new fold in vim, it folds the entire file.  Why?
(`foldmethod=manual`)

e.g.,

1. `zi` (all folds are now open)
2. `zi` (all folds are now closed)
3. lines 1-309 are folded closed, and lines 617-662 are folded closed (file has 662 lines)
4. my cursor is on line 377
5. I do `zfG` to fold all lines from line 377 to end-of-file
   **Expected**: lines 377 thru end-of-file are closed, and lines 310-366 are visible
   **Actual**: all lines in file are closed

Workaround:

1. `zD` (delete all folds)
2. `:1,309fold` (fold 1-309)
3. `:377,$fold` (fold 377-eof)

My fold* settings:

```
  foldclose=
  foldcolumn=0
  foldenable
  foldexpr=0
  foldignore=#
  foldlevel=0
  foldlevelstart=-1
  foldmarker={{{,}}}
  foldmethod=manual
  foldminlines=1
  foldnestmax=20
  foldopen=block,hor,mark,percent,quickfix,tag,undo
  foldtext=foldtext()
```

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because line 377 (where I was creating a new fold) was within an existing *open* fold that started at line 1 of the file.  So when I created the new fold, it increased the size of the existing open fold and closed it, causing the entire file to be folded closed.

To debug this, `:set foldcolumn=12` shows open folds.  And `zM` closes all open folds.

Note also that I thought `zi` toggled open/closed all folds, but that's not true.  `zM` closes all folds, and `zR` opens all folds.

[I got the answer from [this vi.stackexchange.com question]](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26970/why-does-creating-a-new-fold-sometimes-cause-the-entire-file-to-be-folded)